# Force JSON.NET to include milliseconds when serializing DateTime (even if ms component is zero)

Tags: c#, json, datetime, serialization, json.net

I'm using JSON.NET to serialize DateTime values directly from object instances (not using DateTime.ToString() with formatter).

Is there a way to force JSON.NET to include milliseconds in the serialization even if the millisecond component of the DateTime is zero?

Background: I have a very slow web service consumer for this JSON endpoint. Conditional logic is expensive for the consumer, so I'd like to provide the same data formatting every time.

Comment: it might be a good idea to explain the set of circumstances that lead you to wanting to do this

Answer (score 62, accepted):

We ran into this same issue on my current project.  We are using Web API (and hence JSON.Net) to implement a REST API.  We discovered that, when serializing `DateTime` objects, JSON.Net omits the trailing zeros from the milliseconds, or omits the milliseconds from the date entirely if it is zero.  Our clients were expecting a fixed-length date-time string, with exactly 3 digits for the milliseconds.  We fixed it by doing the following in `Application_Start()`:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = HttpConfiguration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
IsoDateTimeConverter dateConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter 
{ 
    DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'" 
};
settings.Converters.Add(dateConverter);
```

If you're not using Web API, you can do the same thing by creating a new instance of `JsonSerializerSettings`, adding the `IsoDateTimeConverter` to it as shown above, then passing the serializer settings to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`.

Note: If you're serializing a `DateTimeOffset` or a local `DateTime` and you want to include the timezone offset, replace the quoted `'Z'` in the above format with an unquoted `K`.
See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) in the documentation for more info.

Comment: Your approach with my performance code actually sits at about a 153ms to parse. It seems that performance is pretty important, that's why I bring it up. They say that a person notices a delay after about 200ms, so you only end up having about 43ms left to account for network usage, database access, etc.

Comment: My answer simply attempts to address the OP's question about how to get JSON.Net to always include the milliseconds when formatting dates.  It does not make a performance claim of any kind.

Comment: Yeah that's fine, I'm just adding information that might help the OP or someone along the way later on.

Comment: This helped, thanks. I'm not sure why there are single quotes in the format string, though. I used `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"`.

Comment: @jrummell The single quotes denote the start and end of a literal character within the format, i.e. those that are not intended to be replaced with a part of the date.  Here, it doesn't really matter because none of the literal characters `-`, `T`, `:`, and `Z` can be confused with formatting specifier characters.  On the other hand, if you wanted to put a literal `M`, for example, in the format somewhere you would definitely need to quote it.  See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) in the documentation for more info.

Comment: @jrummel: The literal delimiters could matter even in this case. For example, if your current culture was *"it-IT"* then your time portion would be converted to something like *"12.31.42"* if you didn't treat the *":"* separator as a literal by quoting it.

Comment: This was helpful. Fix the issue I was having with angular uib-datepicker. Thanks @BrianRogers

Comment: @BrianRogers This resolved my issue with formatting `DateTime` properties on GETs, but now if I attempt to POST a viewmodel with a DateTime property and the value I'm submitting is eg. `2017-03-01`, it will fail to bind the model completely and the viewmodel will be null.  Any way around this?

Comment: @im1dermike - You should [post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) detailing the problem you are having, including code if possible.  The comments section isn't the appropriate place for Q&A.  In the new question you can link back to this one one if it helps to provide context.

Comment: Thanks. I added your code into WebApiConfig.Register(HttpConfiguration config) method as a single line like this: config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff" });

Answer (score 0):

For any Java people finding this answer and wanting to parse such .NET default-formatted timestamps, I wanted to note a Java 8 (`java.time.*`) approach for parsing the format:

```
public static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER =
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                                  .appendFraction(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 0, 3, true)
                                  .toFormatter();
...
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, FORMATTER);
```

This says to expect 0-3 digits of fractional milliseconds, with `true` for an expected decimal point. It correctly interprets, say, ".47" as 470 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when working with JsonWriter and needed to resolve it because we observed that Javascript date libraries such as Day.js prefer milliseconds to have 3 digits. This question led me to the resolution, so I thought to share it in case others have a use-case like mine:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw)) {
    writer.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None;
    writer.DateFormatString="yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff''";
    writer.WriteStartObject();

    DateTime? date = new DateTime(2021,12,30,23,59,40,250);
    writer.WritePropertyName("Date1");
    writer.WriteValue(date);

    date = new DateTime(2021, 12, 30, 23, 59, 40, 555);
    writer.WritePropertyName("Date2");
    writer.WriteValue(date);

    date = new DateTime(2021, 12, 30, 23, 59, 40, 0);
    writer.WritePropertyName("Date3");
    writer.WriteValue(date);

    date = null;
    writer.WritePropertyName("DateNULL");
    writer.WriteValue(date);
    writer.WriteEndObject();
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

This produces:

```
{
    "Date1": "2021-12-30T23:59:40.250",
    "Date2": "2021-12-30T23:59:40.555",
    "Date3": "2021-12-30T23:59:40.000",
    "DateNULL": null
}
```

The important line I needed to add was:

```
writer.DateFormatString="yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff''";
```